# Advanced selection Keymaps settings

Tags: shortcut, selection-tools, select, keymap

Half a year ago i was browsing this forum and i found a topic with the "selection keymaps".
A man posted a screenshot with keymaps settings but it was some advanced selection settings. It wasn't some "mesh.loop_select" stuff, it was some deeper select keys. Under that setting he opened a minimised window with more settings like on my screenshot with "Box Select".
[image]

I can't remember what it was. I was looking a whole day trying to find this page. Im sorry, but maybe someone will understand what i mean and help me.

Comment: If you click on the little right-facing triangle beside the 'Gesture Box' heading the settings section will be expanded below it. The same applies to all the 'Box Select' settings below it.

Comment: What is it exactly that you are asking? Are you looking for some specific setting? Or do you just want to know how to expand the hierarchies to expand the advanced settings?

Comment: I was searching how to change my select keys, coz im a Maya user. Now in looking to change my select setting, because they are not the same in UV window.
Maybe its the "select" keymap. i mean just a select (like lmb) where do i find this key?

Comment: What do you mean by "they are not the same in the UV window"? What exactly is not the same in the UV window?

Comment: Selection keys are different in sticky UV section. So im trying to set it identical keys as in 3d section. Sorry to bother you, im gonna go look for this topic

Comment: Ok. I've never used that mode in the UV editor. The Blender manual section about it is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv/selecting.html#sticky-selection-mode) if it helps.